# Mongoose paginate - count total documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose, pagination

I am using Mongoose paginate with search and filter queries for a schema called Thought. In my thought index .ejs template, I am displaying 40 records on each page using a forEach loop:

```
<% thoughts.docs.forEach(function(thought, i) { %>
```

There is a Show More button to click for the next 40 records:

```
            <div id="box-show-more" class="box-show-more">
                <button class="show-more" id="showMoreBtn" data-page="<%= thoughts.page + 1 %>">Show More</button>
            </div>
```

When a search/filter is applied on the author of the record, many of the authors have less than 40 records, but currently, the Show More button is still displayed. In my controller, the pagination is defined like this:

```
    const thoughts = await Thought.paginate(queryObject, {
        page: req.query.page || 1,
        limit: 40,
        sort: { 'createdAt': -1},
        populate: 'likes',
        collation: { locale: "en" }
    });
```

I want to include a count of the total documents, so I can add a wrapper around the Show More button like, 'if more than 40 records, display Show More button'. But I'm unsure how to include a count in the pagination query. In Mongoose docs a can see there is a field called 'totalDocs', but I'm unsure where to include this or how to return the value from it and use in my .ejs template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which library/plugin for mongoose-pagination you are using, but considering [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate-v2) it should be fairly straight-forward:

```
const result = await Thought.paginate(queryObject, {
      page: req.query.page || 1,
      limit: 40,     
      populate: 'likes'       
});

console.log(result.totalDocs);
```

The object returned from the `paginate` call will contain a property `totalDocs` which yields the total number of documents in collection that match your query.

Comment: this returns 'result is not defined'

Comment: This surprises me - are you sure you assigned the awaited promise to `result`, i.e. `const result = await ...` ?

Comment: Thanks @eol actually your suggestion was correct; the issue was that the returned field seems to be named 'total' rather than 'totalDocs' (though looking at the docs it does suggest totalDocs, unsure why that is). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I made this Pagination Service which can be used with Mongo

```js
import mongoose, { Model } from "mongoose";

/**
 * Represents a pagination service.
 * This class helps with managing pagination for a given Mongoose model.
 */

export interface PaginatedResponse {
  result: any[];
  hasNextPage: Boolean;
  hasPreviousPage: Boolean;
}

export default class PaginationService {
  private model: Model<any>;

  /**
   * Create a PaginationService instance.
   * @param {mongoose.Model} model - The Mongoose model to paginate.
   */

  constructor(model: Model<any>) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  private _page_size: number = 10; // Default size is 10

  /**
   * Gets or sets the page size.
   * @default 10
   */

  get page_size(): number {
    return this._page_size;
  }

  set page_size(newSize: number) {
    if (newSize <= 0) {
      throw new Error("Size must be a positive number");
    }
    this._page_size = newSize;
  }

  /**
   * Get Paginated Response
   * Next and Previous page as Boolean
   */

  async getPaginatedResponce(page: number): Promise<PaginatedResponse> {
    const totalDocumentsRecords = await this.model.countDocuments({});

    // Calculate the total number of pages
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalDocumentsRecords / this.page_size);

    // Determine if there's page
    const hasNextPage = page < totalPages;
    const hasPreviousPage = page > 1;

    const result = await this.model
      .find()
      .limit(this.page_size)
      .skip((page - 1) * this.page_size)
      .exec();

    const response: PaginatedResponse = {
      result,
      hasNextPage,
      hasPreviousPage,
    };

    return response;
  }
}
```

How to use it? here's how

```js
import PaginationService, {
  PaginatedResponse,
} from "@/services/Pagination/Pagination";

const pagination = new PaginationService(anyMongoModel);
    pagination.page_size = 2;

let page = 1

let paginated_response: PaginatedResponse = await pagination.getPaginatedResponse(page);
```

You can tweek it to handle more scenarios.